# How to retrieve a list of available/installed fonts in android?

Tags: java, android, fonts

In Java I would do something like:

```
java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment ge = 
                      java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Font[] fonts = ge.getAllFonts();
```

is there an Android equivalent?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Taken from Mark Murphy's answer on the Android Developers mailing list:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html
>
> There are only three fonts: normal
>   (Droid Sans), serif (Droid Serif), and
>   monospace (Droid Sans Mono).
>
> While there may be additional fonts
>   buried in WebKit somewhere, they
>   appear to be inaccessible to
>   developers outside of WebKit. :-(
>
> The only other fonts are any TrueType ones you bundle with your application.

Edit: Roboto is a new font which came in with Android 4.0. You can use this library project to use it in all versions back to API level 4 https://github.com/mcalliph/roboto-text-view

Comment: I... can actually work with that... Gotta appreciate the simplicity of options.

Comment: Can anyone say font fragmentation? /jk

Comment: There's no problem. You can use any font you like and just include it in your project. Works perfectly

Comment: until you work in web development, and start cursing at Android for not even supporting Arial. That's just sad.

Comment: Is it still true there is only Droid?  What is this Roboto thing? http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html

Comment: Roboto is a new font which came in with Android 4.0. You can use this library project to use it in all versions back to API level 4 https://github.com/mcalliph/roboto-text-view

Comment: I don't see how this is marked as the answer as it does not address to the issue of "listing the installed fonts". Apostolos' should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 29):

Regarding the actual question, here is a way to create a list of all available fonts installed:

```
String path = "/system/fonts";
File file = new File(path);
File ff[] = file.listFiles();
```

Array ff[] will contain all the font files.

Comment: how can i used particular font file and apply that font in rich text ?

Comment: This is the actual answer to OP's question.

Comment: How to identify if particular font only has numbers or only has alphabets? I want to use only fonts which is complete set of alphanumeric + special characters.

Comment: I am sorry @Vrajesh for not responding - I just got a notification on this thread by stackoverflow ...I am not sure what you are asking ... If you are asking something more than just picking up a font file from the ff[] list, it's beyond the question and at this moment I don't have an answer.

Comment: @Nougat, your question is also bequond this thread's question. However, I can suggest off hand that you try to print all characters with one or more of the fonts in the list and see what you get ... (There might be a shorter and more efficient method though ...)

Comment: @Apostolos Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 9):

There are only 3 fonts available as part of android; normal (Droid Sans), serif (Droid Serif),
 and monospace (Droid Sans Mono).

Apps can include their own truetype fonts but can't install them for use by other apps.

- http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg44221.html

couple of links about the fonts:

- http://www.forbes.com/2008/09/25/font-android-g1-tech-wire-cx_ew_0926font.html
- http://www.droidfonts.com/droidfonts/about/

Comment: From android 4.1 - JellyBean, the following Roboto font families are available: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13329907/502187

Answer (score 1):

From Android 29, giving you an actual collection of `android.graphics.fonts.Font`, there is `SystemFonts.getAvailableFonts()`

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/fonts/SystemFonts?hl=en#getAvailableFonts()

Comment: With this, I see 288 whereas with Apostolos' answer there are 328 files

Answer (score 0):

This answer isn't a programmatic solution, but the actual ttf fonts seem to be stored in the /system/fonts directory. Use `adb shell ls /system/fonts` to list them, or `adb pull /system/fonts` to transfer all of them to the connected computer (adb will create a folder named "fonts").

Answer (score -3):

Android includes 3 base fonts, but unlike iOS, allow you to use just about any font you'd like. You can simply embed it with your app, instead of being limited to a preset list of fonts like Apple does (Apple doesn't allow font embedding). Pretty convenient.

Note that this is for Android itself, but web browsers (including the basic pre-installed Android web browser) does support all the standard HTML fonts.

Comment: This is no longer true - iOS 4+ allows apps to embed their own fonts, in addition to the 58 font families provided by iOS.

Comment: And those 58 cover the gamut if you're not doing anything off-the-wall with fonts: http://iosfonts.com

Comment: Not helpful to come along over a year after the OP and use your answer just as an opportunity to slam iOS -- and ineffectively at that. No information in this answer that is useful to the OP nor to those of us coming along later looking for an answer to the question.