# Which fonts can I use for text in Canvas and How do I get bold style?

Tags: android

I'm using text in canvas like this:

```
paintTextTime.setAntiAlias(true);
paintTextTime.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paintTextTime.setTextSize(60);
canvas.drawText(stringPlayTime, 220, 180, paintTextTime);
```

My question is how do I know which font I can use and how do I set the style of font to bold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily change font by loading a new [TypeFace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html). You can put any TTF font in your assets folder and load it using:

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "myfont.ttf");
```

I would suggest that you cache the loaded font to [prevent memory leaks on older Android versions](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904):

```
public class FontCache {

    private static Hashtable<String, Typeface> fontCache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(String name, Context context) {
        Typeface tf = fontCache.get(name);
        if(tf == null) {
            try {
                tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), name);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            fontCache.put(name, tf);
        }
        return tf;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Typeface tf = FontCache.get(context, "myfont.ttf");
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTypeface(tf);
canvas.drawText("Lorem ipsum", 0, 0, paint);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there only one type of fontface available in the device or is there list och which fonts that are available?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532397/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-available-installed-fonts-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Google `android typeface`. [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) is the first result and is most likely what you are looking for.

Comment: You can also download custom fonts if you feel like it or check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.create("Helvetica",Typeface.BOLD);

Paint paint = new Paint();

paint.setTypeface(tf);

canvas.drawText("Sample text in bold Helvetica",0,0,paint);
```