# Android get list of installed fonts

Tags: android, fonts, android-typeface

I'm developing app with possible UI customization by user and would like to allow font textStyle, typeFace and fontFamily selection.
Is it possible to get the list of installed fonts on Android device programmatically?

As for now I know that Roboto fonts were presented in Android 4.1, and one more font was added in Android 4.2 ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android/13329907#13329907))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532397/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-available-installed-fonts-in-android

Comment: @alecnash thank you, but provided answer is 3-years old, now there are new Roboto fonts. Maybe smth changed now?