# Which persian fonts are available to use in android app

Tags: android, fonts, persian

I have an app with educational context I want to use an appropriate Persian font for reading. how can I know which fonts are available to use? (I mean, I do not want to download external one) and can anyone suggest a good Persian font for educational context?

Comment: follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532397/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-available-installed-fonts-in-android)

Comment: There are only three fonts: normal (Droid Sans), serif (Droid Serif), and monospace (Droid Sans Mono).

While there may be additional fonts buried in WebKit somewhere, they appear to be inaccessible to developers outside of WebKit. :-(

The only other fonts are any TrueType ones you bundle with your application.

Comment: @sud I am looking for persian fonts, I read a file in my app, Its context is written in persian but in my phone its shown with arabic font.

Comment: the droid has availabilty of some persian fonts.. if your font comes under droid then only you can use it

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can custom the fonts based on the view your looking for Download a font from internet and put it under assets/fonts folder.

```
  tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
  tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);

  Typeface face= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/font.ttf");
  tv1.setTypeface(face);

  Typeface face1= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/font1.ttf");
  tv2.setTypeface(face1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it is not an answer to my question

Answer (score 2):

"Noto" is a standard Font for other Languages.
You can find "Noto" -- https://www.google.com/get/noto/

Answer (score 0):

"Droid Arabic Naskh" is good and support persian, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Persian, especially for educational content, then you have no choice but to download and use the external font, for example:
[Persian font](https://github.com/rastikerdar/vazirmatn/releases/tag/v33.003).

The `Noto` font mentioned in another answer does not have a Persian variant. And  Arabic script while very similar still has some differences with Persian.